# Max of Two Floor Functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm currently working on a graph theory problem and need to find

$\max{\Bigg(\Big\lfloor \dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4} \Big\rfloor, \; 3\Big\lfloor \dfrac{n^2}{4}} \Big\rfloor \Bigg).$

Graphically, I can see that  $3\Big\lfloor \dfrac{n^2}{4} \Big\rfloor > \Big\lfloor \dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4} \Big\rfloor$, for $n \geq 2$ (which isn't an issue).

I'm just wondering how I could go about proving it - identities, induction, etc? Ideally not something too complex as this is an introductory course and the end of a longer problem. Thanks!

P.S. If it helps, $\dfrac{n^2}{4}$ is a natural number greater than $0$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): work and show some thoughts, using the definition of the floor function.

Comment: Hint. You can ignore the floor since eventually $3n^2$ is a lot bigger than $(n+1)^2$.

Comment: If $\frac{n^2}{4}$ is a natural number why didn't you make the obvious simplification? Posting a question here without doing that kind of simplifications reflects bad on you. It looks like you didn't even try a little to solve the problem.

Comment: Is $n$ also a natural number?

Comment: $$\max\left( ~\lfloor A\rfloor, ~\lfloor B\rfloor ~\right) = \left\lfloor ~\max(A,B) ~\right\rfloor.$$  That is, if $~A < B,~$ then $~\lfloor A\rfloor \leq \lfloor B\rfloor.$

Answer (score 2):

You say that $n^2/4$ is a natural number, so $n$ must be even; let's call it $2k$. Then for $n > 2$, we have $k > 1$, and want to show that
\begin{align}
3\Big\lfloor \dfrac{n^2}{4} \Big\rfloor & > \Big\lfloor \dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4}\Big\rfloor  & \text{ i.e., that}\\ 
3 \dfrac{(2k)^2}{4} & > \Big\lfloor \dfrac{(2k+1)^2}{4}\Big\rfloor & \text{ or} \\
3 k^2 & > \Big\lfloor \dfrac{(4k^2 + 4k + 1)}{4}\Big\rfloor & \text{ or } \\
3 k^2 & > \Big\lfloor k^2 + k + \frac14 \Big\rfloor 
\end{align}

Now because (for $k \ge 1$) we know that (i) $k^2 \ge k$ and (ii) $k^2 \ge 1$, we can say that

\begin{align}
3 k^2 &= k^2 + k^2 + k^2 \\ 
& \ge k^2 + k + 1 \\
& > k^2 + k + 1/4 \\
& \ge \lfloor k^2 + k + \frac14 \rfloor 
\end{align}

so there's your proof.

By the way, the book "Concrete Mathematics" gives some quite general tools for working with floors/ceilings/mod/div/ etc., in case you want to learn more.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: I found it a perfectly reasonable question; the context was "I'm trying to do graph theory and I'm stuck on doing something with the floor function." I showed a way to do something with floor functions. Maybe I just did someone's homework for them, but maybe I taught them something about manipulating floor/ceiling, and about doing (crude) estimates. Not every 1-point user automatically is asking a bad question.

Comment: @anne - I appreciate you reaching out about the quality of the post, and I do feel that I gave enough context as well as my personal thoughts, in conjunction with defining the problem clearly. In honesty, I felt like I was missing something trivial, since this comes at the end of a tedious calculation and I didn't think more context was needed; I do apologize if this is a more complicated question, which is what this is seeming to me. Thanks for the quality standard policy guide as well!

Comment: @john - Thanks for the answer and the recommended reading! I think I need a bit more practice with floor functions so I'll definitely check it out.